# Raw material button not responding to clicks flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Where am I supposed to place the material as the parent of the Raw material button so that it can respond to clicks and show splash color.
The widget tree looks like below.

```
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return new Container(
     child: new Center(
     child: new Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          child: new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: new Container(
              child: new AudioComponent(
                updateMe: [WatchableAudioProperties.audioPlayerState],
                    playerBuilder: (BuildContext context, AudioPlayer 
                     player,
                    Widget child) {
                    IconData icon = Icons.play_arrow;

                  return new RawMaterialButton(
                    shape: new CircleBorder(),
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    splashColor: lightAccentColor,
                    highlightColor: lightAccentColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                    elevation: 10.0,
                    highlightElevation: 5.0,
                    onPressed: (){},
                    child: new Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: new Icon(
                        icon,
                        color: accentColor,
                        size: 50.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        new Container(
          height: 151.0,
          width: 151.0,
          child: waves,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  );
 }
```

If I add another container onto the stack and put a similar RawMaterial button, it responds as required even without adding a material widget anywhere. What I don't understand why the RawButton in the first container in the stack is not working

Comment: Maybe your `Container` covers the buttons, so it doesnt get touch input

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect to have your `RawMaterialButton` react when you have the following code in it's definition?

```
onPressed: (){},
```

Comment: Any button reacts with that as the code. It is supposed to give it the functionality of a button without having a function to perform